# take user input and store into structure by calling function

Tags: c, function, struct

Creating a bank account "detail filling form" in C language as mini project . Where I want that user enter the detail but it does not give chance to enter name .

**Structure**

```
#define NAME_SIZE 100;   
struct detail
        {
            char name[50];
            int money, accnumber, accyear;
        };
```

//calling **function** with passing the argument ARRAY_SIZE

```
int detail(int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
   struct detail user[ARRAY_SIZE];
   for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; ++index)
    {
    printf("Enter details of Employee %d\n\n", index + 1);
    printf("Enter your name: \n");
    fgets(user[index].name, NAME_SIZE, stdin);    //Error Line
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter money number: ");
    scanf("%d", &user[index].money);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter account number: ");
    scanf("%d", &user[index].accnumber);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter year : ");
    scanf("%d", &user[index].accyear);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; ++index)
    {
        printf("User Name : %s", user[index].name);
        printf("Account Number : %d\n", user[index].accnumber);
        printf("Money : %d\n", user[index].money);
        printf("Year : %d\n\n", user[index].accyear);
    }
return 0;
}
```

**this is the output I get**

The program is automatically came at second line without passing any error

```
Enter your name: 
Enter money : 5000   
Enter account number: 0019284834
Enter year : 2022

User Name : 
Account Number : 19284834
Money : 5000
Year : 2022
```

I'm new in programming and glad to see such a great community to clear your doubt .

Comment: Do you do any input before you call detail() that might have left stuff in the input buffer? And doesn't your final scanf in the loop leave a line ending in the input buffer for the fgets at the beginning to read?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `NAME_SIZE` is set to 0 or 1.

[The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s until n-1 bytes are read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html)

When `NAME_SIZE` <= 1, it just skip, the fgets will passes without getting user input. Use print statements to find out the value of `NAME_SIZE`. Even better, learn to use GDB or LLDB.